# User search fails if name has dots

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, users

On the user's page ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users), [SF](https://serverfault.com/users), [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users), ...), if you type "T.J" (no trailing dot) in the search box you'll see names starting with "T.J" ("[T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247)", "[T.J. Boberek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167513)", "[T.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179824)", etc.) but if you type "T.J." (with the trailing dot, as one normally would) nothing happens. At all. The currently-displayed results don't change (as opposed to showing no matches).

(Related but different bug: [Users Search box doesn't find names with an apostrophe '](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36692))

Comment: @dup voter: It's not an exact duplicate, it's (as I said) related but different. His symptom is different from mine, for a start (I'm not talking about mine being a dot and his being an apostrophe, the actual symptom -- what happens -- is different). (@all: the dup voter chose the question I linked as the dup)

Comment: Given S.Mark's [filter URL](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/filter/t.j.), this seems to be related to [Trailing periods produce a server level 404.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44458/trailing-periods-produce-a-server-level-404)

Comment: Dude, you better change your name :)

Comment: As another *dotted* user, I second this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. I don't know when, but it doesn't happen anymore, so...

Comment: I think upgrading to .NET 4 fixed this. They addressed a lot of dumb legacy ASP.NET limitations on URLs..

Answer (score 5):

I've debugged with Firebug, and I noticed that when I search for [**T.J.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/filter/t.j.) it returns the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404.  The resource you are looking for (or one of
> its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
> temporarily unavailable.   Please review the following URL and make
> sure that it is spelled correctly.

But, when I search for **T.J. Crowder**, it's just fine.

So, it happens when the searched name ends with a dot.

Comment: That's strange, I don't get the 404. I just don't get anything. How are you searching?

Comment: I debugged with firebug, you can also find at here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/filter/t.j.?_=1266918630994

Comment: Ah, that explains it (the 404 discrepancy), I wasn't looking under the covers, just reporting the actual UX.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Microsoft Windows has problems with names that end in a dot. Using ntfs-3g in linux to create a directory named `cannot_open.` and then trying to open it from Windows will result in an error »directory does not exist« (or something similar, it's been some time since I've used Windows with such a folder)