# Trailing periods produce a server level 404

Tags: bug, status-deferred, hyperlinks, 404-not-found

A [meta.SE bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5101/server-error-in-application-from-bad-url) came up which also applies to SOFU.

Any URL path ending in a dot produces a [low-level server 404](https://stackoverflow.com/nosuchpageexists.), rather than the [usual SO 404](https://stackoverflow.com/nosuchpagexists), even when the dot is part of a string which is supposed to be [ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet.).

Shouldn't the URLs be sanitized before they are processed so that special characters are treated as literals?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40131/user-search-fails-if-name-has-dots

Comment: I can't believe you rolled back my edit, @Downvoter. That was a *very* relevant question.

Comment: It was already there in the question @mmy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a bug deep, deep in the .NET framework. Seriously.

See:

[How to create a Uri instance parsed with GenericUriParserOptions.DontCompressPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515959/how-to-create-a-uri-instance-parsed-with-genericuriparseroptions-dontcompresspath)

and related connect item, **`System.Uri` incorrectly strips trailing dots**

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386695/system-uri-incorrectly-strips-trailing-dots?wa=wsignin1.0#tabs

Comment: Are we inventing `[status-framework-fault]`?

Comment: `[status-byframeworkdesign]`

Answer (score 5):

This bug has been fixed. Now:

- https://stackoverflow.com/nosuchpageexists and [`https://stackoverflow.com/nosuchpageexists.`](https://stackoverflow.com/nosuchpageexists.) produce the same result (the usual Stack Overflow 404 page with the polyglot program).
- Valid question URLs followed by one or more `.`s now redirect to the canonical question URL: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44458/trailing-periods-produce-a-server-level-404....`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44458/trailing-periods-produce-a-server-level-404....) redirects to [Trailing periods produce a server level 404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44458/trailing-periods-produce-a-server-level-404)