# Is it possible to search for words with an apostrophe, like "doesn't"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I've spent a good 10 minutes looking for this question. The only one I found is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/users-search-box-doesnt-find-names-with-an-apostrophe) one which may be, at the *cause* level, the same. However, it was referring to a different search box, and it was never answered.

When searching for a word with an apostrophe, SO filters out the apostrophe. Thus a search for **can't** finds **cant** but does *not* find **can't**. I tried escaping it with backslash (**can\'t**), and I tried two apostrophes (**can''t**), and I tried quoting it (**"can't"**) all to no avail. Is there a way to make this work? Is this a bug?

There is a work-around: use google to search SO instead. But that's not pretty.

Edit: If this is by-design, could the search engine be modified to ignore apostrophes in question titles, such that **can't** == **cant**?

Answer (score 3):

I just checked on Super User and found that [searching for "can't"](https://superuser.com/search?q=can%27t) some pages, after editing out the "can't", [still show up](https://superuser.com/questions/123443/why-i-cant-see-picture-in-rtf-opened-with-textedit). They just aren't highlighted.

To extend on that, note that URL slugs don't have apostrophes. If the search includes the URL (which from the above example it does) then I would assume apostrophes aren't an issue.

Other than that, I'd guess it's `feature-by-design` because they remove `'` and `"` from queries.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about titles not having apostrophes. Titles *do* have apostrophes, but URLs don't. If the search only looked at URLs, then "can't" would get both "cant" and "can't". Ergo the search (on SO and Meta at least) seems to be looking at titles, and deciding that "can't" (in the title) != "cant" (in the de-apostrophe'd search string). It seems that if the search engine would de-apostrophe the titles it searched, this problem would go away.

Comment: Yes, the URL string doesn't have any apostrophes, that's what I meant.

Comment: `Apostrophe's` shouldn't have any apostrophes.

Answer (score 2):

[After the latest search changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), we'll search any term in quotes as an exact match, including symbols such as apostrophes.  For example, compare searching for ["cant"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cant%22) vs ["can't"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22can%27t%22).