# Impossible to search for usernames with punctuation in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, search

When you do a search in chat, the punctuation is removed. For example, [searching T.E.D.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation&filter=T.E.D) gives me everyone with `/ted/i`, but it doesn't catch [the one user named T.E.D.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/39427/t-e-d).

The same thing goes for [searching F'x](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation&filter=F%27x) to find [F'x](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/4806/fx). Or searching [J.M.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation&filter=J.M.) to find [J.M.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/70/j-m).

The context of this is that I was looking for T.E.D. (new mod) so that I could fix his chat profile so that it is recognized by the TL bot. I couldn't find him, no matter what I searched -- finally I searched "D", sorted by reputation, found the pages where his approximate total rep would fit (unfortunately, chat rep != flair rep, and I didn't want to jQuery-calculate it), and looked through a bunch of them. I really shouldn't have to do this.

It occurs to me that if [Link to chat user from profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136504/link-to-chat-user-from-profile-page) was implemented, this would be pretty much a non-issue. < /plug >

Comment: Hm, as phrased, this seems like a duplicate of your earlier feature request, perhaps this makes more sense as a bug report (one possible solution to which might be your earlier feature request)?

Comment: @Yannis: You're right, it's more of a bug. Note that while solving the other issue makes this pretty a non-issue (as in, it doesn't matter as you still have an easy pathway), the fact remains that the chat search doesn't like punctuation, which still isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126094/cannot-reply-users-with-only-two-alphanumeric-characters-in-their-username/139959#139959) required a change to how user names are normalized; I missed the user name search when making this change. Fixed now.