# Why are usernames allowed to be composed entirely of non-visible Unicode characters?

Tags: discussion, display-names, unicode

[This user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3936/) on Ask Different appears to have no name due to invisible Unicode characters:

[image]

he's the #2 user on the site:

[image]

Why is that allowed? I think it is confusing for users, e.g. when they will see at the bottom of an answer:

[image]

It's not clear who answered, not clear what the rep numbers and badges are related to, and not clear how you can @reply to that user in the comments!

Comment: Very much related: [Cannot @ reply to users with usernames composed of non-visible unicode characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195798/152859)

Comment: @Bart I understand how it works, I'm actually questioning why `U+034F ͏COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER` is allowed as a “character” in usernames

Comment: Yup; I'm sure @ShaWizDowArd knows that; he's just posting that because it was someone else recently who was taken aback by a user with such a name.

Comment: @AndrewBarber that's the same user actually. Guess he's laughing his invisible a$$ off now seeing all the havoc he's causing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ahh... well, how could *I* know it was the same user... since I can't see his name, and all!?!?!?! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber reputation, to begin with... ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Next you'll tell me the user ID. Pshaw!

Comment: User IDs @AndrewBarber ... geez, who voted for you in the elec...ah..nevermind.

Comment: how can i do that. Alt+255 doesn't work.

Comment: Because it's hilarious.

Comment: Interesting, it also eats the link to the user account. Maybe we could show a placeholder in such instances? I propose "Keyser Söze".

Comment: Funny how of all people this question had to be asked by someone who himself is unpingable in chat. Jealousy? Alter ego? BRB posting on Skeptics.

Comment: @ЯegDwight I am [not unpingable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139959/142977) anymore :(

Comment: I found this thread because I came across that [user on SU](http://superuser.com/users/69039/) today. Not only are they using a non-displaying character for their name, but they are using a blank avatar as well (an 80x80 black PNG set to transparent). While it seems clever (and was probably what they were trying to do), it also seems like a pointless, meaningless attempt to subvert the system.

Answer (score 5):

Because Unicode in general is allowed in order to support multiple languages, and because that character, [U+034F ͏COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER](https://codepoints.net/U+034F), is not tagged as "white space" in the Unicode database.

It would need some additional work to enumerate all the non-visible non-whitespace characters and ensure that the input validation also rejects strings that contain no visible characters.

Unicode doesn't have a "visible" property, otherwise this would be easy.

Comment: As usual, huge oversight of those who created Unicode, releasing a monster into the wild, without proper constraints. ;)