# Comment posted by?

Tags: discussion, support

Ok, this is weird.

Generally the commentator name is at the end of comment, but for the below comment(Pic) i can't find the commentator link.
[image]

Here is the **[Question link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment318407_3122)**

Comment: There was a similar question asking about hidden/invisible users with such characters in their display names.

Comment: [Why are usernames allowed to be composed entirely of non-visible Unicode characters?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196407/why-are-usernames-allowed-to-be-composed-entirely-of-non-visible-unicode-charact) @hjpotter92

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have circled the name. The user is using some special Unicode characters are part of his name, causing the effect you see, including a "broken" link. It is in fact this user: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163265/

Comment: Isn't a broken link due to allowed characters in username a bug? These chars should either be disallowed at name setting form, like the moderator's diamond is, or site should handle them without any such problems.

Comment: @Mołot That is more or less under discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196407/why-are-usernames-allowed-to-be-composed-entirely-of-non-visible-unicode-charact

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Haven't found it, but I was using wrong keywords.